# Negation fails to match operators in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I have the following antlr4 grammar:

```
grammar nota;
word: WORD;
WORD: ~'a'; //match anything that isn't an 'a'
```

As [the documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md) describes this negates the set of characters for a single given character or character range.

Then I try to parse some test case texts (a single character input per test case):
`a` fails expectedly
`b` succeeds expectedly
`$` succeeds expectedly
**`+` fails unexpectedly**
**`=` fails unexpectedly**
`§` succeeds expectedly
`\` succeeds expectedly
**`/` fails unexpectedly**
`~` succeeds expectedly

In case it matters I'm using nodejs' antlr4ts 0.5.0-alpha.4.
The default error listener prints for example

> line 1:0 mismatched input '+' expecting WORD

Am I misunderstanding antlr's `~` operator?
Is this a bug that should be reported? I'm not seeing anything in the [github issue tracker](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues?q=is%3Aissue+operator+negation).

Edit: In an attempt to work around the error I changed the grammar to `WORD: '+'|~'a';`, but that also fails to match `+` for some strange reason.

This also fails to parse `+`:

```
grammar nota;
word: WORD | OPERATORS;
OPERATORS: '+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'=';
WORD: ~'a';
```

This succeeds parsing `+`:

```
grammar nota;
word: WORD | '+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'=';
WORD: ~'a';
```

Comment: The first grammar and examples just underneath parse as expected for Java, C#, and JavaScript (with 4.9.2-snapshot and NodeJs 14.15.4). I don't think the TS target is done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that with `0.5.0-alpha.4`.

Given the grammar:

```
grammar nota;
word: WORD;
WORD: ~'a';
```

running this code:

```
import { CharStreams, CommonTokenStream } from 'antlr4ts';
import { notaLexer } from './parser/notaLexer';
import { notaParser } from './parser/notaParser';

const lexer = new notaLexer(CharStreams.fromString("+"));
const parser = new notaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
const root = parser.word();

console.log(root.toInfoString(parser));
```

does not produce any error or warning.

I suspect you did not post the entire grammar. Probably, you have some `'+'` literal inside a parser rule, or `'+'` is already matched by a lexer rule defined before the `WORD` rule. The lexer works in a very simple way:

1. try to match as much characters as possible for each rule
2. if 2 or more rules match the same amount of characters, let the one defined first "win"

So, if you have rules like this:

```
word: WORD;
PLUS : '+';
WORD: ~'a';
```

then the input `"+"` will always become a `PLUS` token. Even if the parser tries to match a `WORD` token.

Comment: For future visitors: It's indeed an Antlr property and has nothing to do with TypeScript or antlr4ts.
`WORD: ~'a';` will match `'+'` just fine, until you add `expr: expr '+' expr;` which causes Antlr to define an ad-hoc lexer rule with an unnamed token `'+'` that has priority over `WORD`. Every character you mention like that automatically gets excluded from `WORD` and you can't do `WORD: ~'a' | '+'` either because the lexer still has to choose which token to use. You can, however, do `word: WORD | '+';` and remember to add all ad-hoc tokens as they come up which is not ideal.